# Degree in homology and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ be a continuous map. One can define the degree of $f$ as the integer $k$ such that $f_* : H_n(S^n) \rightarrow H_n(S^n)$ is multiplication by $k$ on $H_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb Z$. However, it also makes sense so define the degree as the integer $k'$ such that $f^*$ is multiplication by $k'$ on $H^n(S^n)$. Must these two integers agree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

From the [universal coefficient theorem for cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology), we have a *natural* isomorphism $H^n(S^n)\to\hom(H_n(S^n),\mathbb Z)$. Now write what naturality means for a map $f:S^n\to S^n$, and conclude what you want.

Comment: This also tells you what happens for the degree of a map $f:M\to M$ with $M$ a closed orientable manifold, more generally, btw.